# Merge column vectors from the loop in to a single matrix *.mat in matlab [Solved]

Tags: data-mining, matlab, vector-fields

I have an iteration of my algorithm and it gives me a column vector as a result (1899x1 double). I want to form a new matrix composed of these column vectors together sequentially (for example, the 2nd column vector from the iteration will be the 2nd column in the newly formed matrix), like this example:

```
This is 1st iteration
0
0
1
0
This is 2nd iteration
0
0
0
1
This is 3rd iteration
1
1
0
1
```

After merging it should be

```
0  0  1
0  0  1
1  0  0
0  1  1
```

and saved it in *.mat file.

Can anybody help? Since I have 422 files, the vector size should be 422x1899double.I will be thankful if anyone suggest me how to write a loop which can do so. Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be pretty easy, you'll see.

```
A = zeros(422, 1899);  % create a 422x1899 matrix
for i = 1:422
    v = my_algorithm_that_returns_the_column_vector();  % here we run our algo
    A(:,i) = v;  % here we merge the column vector into a matrix
end
save my_file.mat A
```

Comment: Thank you @ociule, but it's not work in my program since the dimension mismatch. In this case, what shall i do?

Comment: Ah, sorry to make u confused. Finally i can make it. A little editing from your example. Thank you. It's working now

Comment: Just edited to include the correct dimensions from your update. Hope it helps